# gettext under Mac OS X Lion for eclipse with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, osx-lion, gettext

I have a Java project in Eclipse which builds with apache maven.

The problem is that the project doesn´t compile correcly because of the gettext function missing.

So I did some search and installed gettext as follows:

Download Gettext from : http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/

Run these commands

```
tar -zxf gettext-0.18.1.1.tar.gz
cd  gettext-0.18.1.1
```

Then in the gettext-0.18.1.1 run these commands

```
./configure
 make
 sudo make install
```

Unfortunately this doesn´t solves my problem.

I also found something about patching gettext on lion here:
https://gist.github.com/1014218
But I don´t really understand what to do here and am not even sure if this would fix my problem.

If I try to compile my project in the terminal with the command:

```
§ maven compile
```

I get this warning:

```
[INFO] [gettext:dist {execution: convert-po-class}]
[INFO] Processing de/de.po
[WARNING] msgfmt --java2 -d /.../workspace/target/classes -r **.**.**.**.Translation -l de /.../workspace/po/de/de.po
```

(... and ** are for privacy reasons)

(In Eclipse also changed the builder from java builder to maven. And if I try to run the project in eclipse and not in the terminal I get this Error:

```
 NoClassDefFoundError: org/xnap/commons/i18n/I18nFactory
```

)

Edit: I also found this link:
http://code.google.com/p/rudix/source/detail?r=0e7c428f9609

But I can´t even find the documents there who I am told to change.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

`I18nFactory` is a class from the `gettext commons` library, so you need to add it to your project's classpath/dependencies. You can find it [here](https://code.google.com/p/gettext-commons/) along some code snippets and a maven configuration example.